# Wordpress running CSS before a button element

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<input type="submit" class="button wp_job_manager_send_application_button" value="Send application">
```

Is the button HTML I am trying to modify.

Wanted Action, Trigger CSS from another plugin (mycred)

It is in `/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-job-manager-applications/templates/application-form.php`
(line 24) For the code on this Pastebin
http://pastebin.com/GVwdSsvy

```
<?php global $post; ?>
<form class="job-manager-application-form job-manager-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() );?>">
    <?php do_action( 'job_application_form_fields_start' ); ?>

    <?php foreach ( $application_fields as $key => $field ) : ?>
        <?php if ( 'output-content' === $field['type'] ) : ?>
            <div class="form-content">
                <h3><?php esc_html_e( $field['label'] ); ?></h3>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $field['description'] ) ) : ?><?php echo wpautop( wp_kses_post( $field['description'] ) ); ?><?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <fieldset class="fieldset-<?php esc_attr_e( $key ); ?>">
                <label for="<?php esc_attr_e( $key ); ?>"><?php echo __( $field['label'] ) . apply_filters( 'submit_job_form_required_label', $field['required'] ? '' : ' <small>' . __( '(optional)', 'wp-job-manager' ) . '</small>', $field ); ?></label>
                <div class="field <?php echo $field['required'] ? 'required-field' : ''; ?>">
                    <?php $class->get_field_template( $key, $field ); ?>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'job_application_form_fields_end' ); ?>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="button wp_job_manager_send_application_button" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Use Token & Apply!', 'wp-job-manager-applications' ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="wp_job_manager_send_application" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo absint( $post->ID ); ?>" />
    </p>
</form>
```

showing as..

```
<input type="submit" class="button wp_job_manager_send_application_button" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Send application', 'wp-job-manager-applications' ); ?>" />
```

It needs to use this CSS when the button is clicked.

```
a.mycred-points-link {http://linkhere.com }
```

I'm at a loss on how to tie this together..

How can I make

```
a.mycred-points-link {http://linkhere.com }
```

run with button click

```
<input type="submit" class="button wp_job_manager_send_application_button" value="Send application">
```

Comment: We can't see any of your code. Please edit your question to be properly formatted.

Comment: okay I'll try again :D .. that was quite dumb of me